# PHP Upload File, Extension Error

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, file-upload

I have searched around and tried everything, my script was working good and i was uploading files correctly, but now i dunno why it still throw the error of file extension that does exist in my array.

Here is my PhpUpload script :

```
<?php
# code...
if(!@include("bootstrap.php")) throw new Exception("Failed to include 'bootstrap'");
else{ 
    $sqldb=new SqlDB;
    $mysqli=$sqldb->DBconnect('localhost','root','root','dbex');
    if (isset($_GET['ref']) && isset($_GET['rooms']) && isset($_GET['showers']) && isset($_GET['parkings']) && isset($_GET['infos']) && isset($_GET['city']) && isset($_GET['surface']) && isset($_GET['price']) && isset($_GET['sup']) && isset($_GET['desc'])) {
        # code...
        if (!empty($_GET['ref']) && !empty($_GET['rooms']) && !empty($_GET['showers']) && !empty($_GET['parkings']) && !empty($_GET['infos']) && !empty($_GET['city']) && !empty($_GET['surface']) && !empty($_GET['price']) && !empty($_GET['sup']) && !empty($_GET['desc'])) {
            # code...
            $ref = $_GET['ref'];
            $rooms = $_GET['rooms'];
            $showers = $_GET['showers'];
            $parkings = $_GET['parkings'];
            $infos = $_GET['infos'];
            $city = $_GET['city'];
            $surface = $_GET['surface'];
            $price = $_GET['price'];
            $sup = $_GET['sup'];
            $desc = $_GET['desc'];

            //File size, path and extensions allowed
            $allowed_filetypes = array('.jpg','.jpeg','.png','.gif');
            $max_filesize = 10485760;
            $path="css/";

            //File name 
            $i=10;

            //File settings
            $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
            $uploadfile=$path.basename($filename);
            $ext = substr($filename, strpos($filename,'.'), strlen($filename)-1);

            //Conditions
            if(!in_array($ext,$allowed_filetypes))
              die('The file you attempted to upload is not allowed.');
            if(filesize($_FILES['fileselect']['tmp_name']) > $max_filesize)
              die('The file you attempted to upload is too large.');
            if (file_exists($upload_path))
                die('File already exist.');
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
                # code...
                die('Line 41');
            }
            else{
                die('error uploading the file');
            }

        }
    }
}

?>
```

It says that the file is not allowed while i have tried to upload an image with '.gif' & '.jpg' extension that exists in my array.

HTML form code (Bootstrap CSS & Js) :

```
<form role="form" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
              <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="fileselect">Images :</label>
              <div class="col-sm-9 upload">
                <!-- Change the wording using a title tag -->
                <input type="file" title="Parcourir..." name="file" multiple="multiple" id="file"/>
                <span class="messages" id="file-name"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group pull-right">
              <div class="col-sm-9">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="submit" name="submit" value="addPro">Ajouter ce bien</button>
              </div>

</div>
</form>
```

Thank you guys !

Comment: Try adding `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your `<form>`

Comment: already tried it not working.

Comment: That's why I posted it as a comment. When it comes to questions like these, I know that it's not 100% sure that it will work and that something else may be contributing to the problem.

Comment: I think I know why. You may have a naming convention conflict.

Comment: you mean between the type, name and id in my html input file tag?

Comment: The guy below (*assuming he is a guy*), made an edit. See what that says.

Comment: Can you be more specefic? thanks.

Comment: The answer given below states *"Edit Why not change the allowed file type array to: array('image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif');"* and *"this should work (atleast it does for me)"* --- So, have you tried it?

Comment: yep i have tried that, i though u were talking about yourself dude

Comment: Ok, notice `$_FILES['file']` and `$_FILES['fileselect']`? That's the conflict I was telling you about earlier. You have 2x `$_FILES['fileselect']` which should be `$_FILES['file']`

Comment: no that wasn't the problem 'cause as you can see i said it drops the die('file not allowed') which means that the extension is where the problim still in, i have tried to upload the file with no extension check and it was working, so it might be there an error in my condition or my `$ext` variable.

Comment: Instead of `$ext = substr($filename, strpos($filename,'.'), strlen($filename)-1);` try `$ext = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));` However, I'm still questioning `['fileselect']`

Comment: still the same problem i have tried to print `$ext` i have got nothing so it ruturns a `NULL` i'm working now to change it

Comment: What is your upload path? I see `$upload_path` but there's nothing assigned to it. I think you need to change that to `$path` since you're setting it in `$path="css/";` probably why it's failing. You also need to add `method="post"` in your form.

Comment: it stucks in the first check, anyways i've found the problem it is in my `$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];` it rutrns `NULL` i dunno why maybe when i set the submit button it doesn't send the file or i dunno, but as i'm using `GET Methode` i can see the file name in my searchbar weired

Comment: I tested your code and got the same thing. But, when I commented out these two lines, it worked. `if (file_exists($path)) die('File already exist.');` I think it has something to do with the fact that's it's checking if the "folder" exists and not the actual file itself. Change it to `if (file_exists($uploadfile))` and it will work.

Comment: what i think me is instead of working with `$_FILE` i'll use my `GET` methode to extract the file name then upload it, till now it may have a problem between `GET`method and the use of `$_FILE`, i'll try my little trick hope it will works

Comment: Have you tried what I suggested? To change `if (file_exists($path))`  to `if (file_exists($uploadfile))` ? This worked for me. Then when I tried to upload the same file, it gave me the `die()` message.

Comment: yes i did and still the same problem, no i've tried the trick with `GET` method and its working now :D, but now i go a problem in `if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile))`

Comment: You can't use `GET` since it's an upload. Try changing all your `$_GET` to `$_REQUEST` and use `method="post"`. When I took out the `method="post"` in mine, it would not upload the file.

Comment: If you have a problem with that now, it's most likely because of `$_FILES['file']` and `$_FILES['fileselect']` least, that's what I think.

Comment: Another thing I noticed, when uploading multiple files, you will need to change `name="file"` to `name="file[]"` should you get any other issues and not be able to upload more than one file. However, when doing so, you'll need a `foreach` loop to handle the multiples.

Comment: Ok, so has your matter been resolved?

Comment: sorry for being late, but still the same problem with the upload, and the `GET' `POST' method as i think are not the issue here, and using `GET' to extract the file's name wasn't really a big issue, because it returns a value so as i got the value in my searchbar it works as the `$_FILE` variable cuz both will return a string that i need.

Comment: I don't know what else to tell you at this point. You will need to either take it up with the other person below who posted an "answer" or continue to debug using `var_dump();` I've done what I could, good luck.

Comment: If you mark this as solved, you should accept the answer that solved it or if you figured it out yourself, put the answer and accept it.

Comment: i have put my answer but i can't accept it, if you can do it pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved, what i did is that i removed the condition where i include my `bootstrap.php`
and then my script worked fine with `POST` method.

```
if (isset($_POST['ref']) && isset($_POST['rooms']) && isset($_POST['showers']) && isset($_POST['parkings']) && isset($_POST['location']) && isset($_POST['typepr']) && isset($_POST['tran']) && isset($_POST['priceper']) && isset($_POST['city']) && isset($_POST['surface']) && isset($_POST['price']) && isset($_POST['sup']) && isset($_POST['desc'])) {
        # code...
        if (!empty($_POST['ref']) && !empty($_POST['rooms']) && !empty($_POST['showers']) && !empty($_POST['parkings']) && !empty($_POST['location']) && !empty($_POST['typepr']) && !empty($_POST['tran']) && !empty($_POST['priceper']) && !empty($_POST['city']) && !empty($_POST['surface']) && !empty($_POST['price']) && !empty($_POST['sup']) && !empty($_POST['desc'])) {
            # code...
            $ref = $_POST['ref'];
            $rooms = $_POST['rooms'];
            $showers = $_POST['showers'];
            $parkings = $_POST['parkings'];
            $location = $_POST['location'];
            $typepr = $_POST['typepr'];
            $tran = $_POST['tran'];
            $priceper = $_POST['priceper'];
            $city = $_POST['city'];
            $surface = $_POST['surface'];
            $price = $_POST['price'];
            $sup = $_POST['sup'];
            $desc = $_POST['desc'];

            //File size, path and extensions allowed
            $allowed_filetypes = array('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.gif');
            $file_type = $_FILES['fileselect']['type'];
            $max_filesize = 10485760;
            $path="css/";

            //File name 
            $i=10;

            //File settings
            $filename = $_FILES['fileselect']['name'];
            $uploadfile=$path.basename($filename);
            $ext = substr($filename, strpos($filename,'.'), strlen($filename)-1);

            //Conditions
            if(!in_array($ext,$allowed_filetypes))
              die('The file you attempted to upload is not allowed.');
            if(filesize($_FILES['fileselect']['tmp_name']) > $max_filesize)
              die('The file you attempted to upload is too large.');
            if (file_exists($uploadfile))
                die('File already exist.');
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileselect']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
                # code...
                die('Line 41');
            }
            else{
                die('error uploading the file');
            }

        }
    }
```

my html code is the same, hope i helped someone here goodluck

Answer (score 2):

The form tag needs  `enctype="multipart/form-data"` thats is needed to upload files

**Edit**
Why not change the allowed file type array to: `array('image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif');`

and say:

```
$file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];

if(!in_array($file_type, $allowed_filetypes)) {
 die('The file you attempted to upload is not allowed.');
}
```

this should work (atleast it does for me)

Comment: i have tried this thanks bro, but still not working :)